# How to get a subset from an OrderedDict?

Tags: python

I have an OrderedDict in Python, and I only want to get the first key-vale pairs. How to get it? For example, to get the first 4 elements, i did the following:

```
subdict = {}

for index, pair in enumerate(my_ordered_dict.items()):
    if index < 4:
       subdict[pair[0]] = pair[1]
```

Is this the good way to do it?

Comment: You can do something like this: `OrderedDict(tuple(my_ordered_dict.items())[:4])`

Comment: I think this is concise, and the only changes unless you plan to use list comprehension.

Answer (score 7):

That approach involves running over the whole dictionary even though you only need the first four elements, checking the index over and over, and manually unpacking the pairs, and manually performing index checking unnecessarily.

Making it short-circuit is easy:

```
subdict = {}
for index, pair in enumerate(my_ordered_dict.items()):
    if index >= 4:
       break  # Ends the loop without iterating all of my_ordered_dict
    subdict[pair[0]] = pair[1]
```

and you can nested the unpacking to get nicer names:

```
subdict = {}
# Inner parentheses mandatory for nested unpacking
for index, (key, val) in enumerate(my_ordered_dict.items()):
    if index >= 4:
       break  # Ends the loop
    subdict[key] = value
```

but you can improve on that [with `itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to remove the manual index checking:

```
from itertools import islice  # At top of file

subdict = {}
# islice lazily produces the first four pairs then stops for you
for key, val in islice(my_ordered_dict.items(), 4):
    subdict[key] = value
```

at which point you can actually one-line the whole thing (because now you have an iterable of exactly the four pairs you want, and the `dict` constructor accepts an iterable of pairs):

```
subdict = dict(islice(my_ordered_dict.items(), 4))
```

Comment: Very nice solution! For any python code I wrote, it seems there is always a much better solution existing!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map function, like this

```
item = dict(map(lambda x: (x, subdict[x]),[*subdict][:4]))
```

Comment: Is dict(tuple(my_ordered_dict.items())[:4]) simpler?

Comment: looks pretty much

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
sub_dict = dict(pair for i, pair in zip(range(4), my_ordered_dict.items()))
```

The length of `zip(a,b)` is equal to the length of the shortest of `a` and `b`, so if `my_ordered_dict.items()` is longer than `4`, `zip(range(4), my_ordered_dict.items()` just takes the first `4` items. These key-value pairs are passed to the `dict` builtin to make a new `dict`.